# angular form set variable equal expression

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following object:

```
  $scope.module.discount = [{
            licences: 0,
            discountPercentage: 0,
            new_value_pr_licence: 0
        }]
```

And the following simple form:

```
    <div class="form-group">
    <label>Pris pr licens</label>
    <div class="input-group m-b">
        <input type="number" class="form-control" ng-model="module.price_pr_licence">
        <span class="input-group-addon">Kr</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <table>
        <thead>
        <th>Licenser</th>
        <th>% rabat</th>
        <th>Ny pris pr stk</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr  ng-repeat="discount in module.discount">
            <td>
                <input class="form-control" ng-model="discount.licences" type="number" required="">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input class="form-control" type="number" ng-model="discount.discountPercentage" required="">
            </td>

            <td>
                <button class="btn btn-sm btn-default">{{module.price_pr_licence * (1-(discount.discountPercentage / 100))}}</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

AS you can see the button's value is an expression:

```
{{module.price_pr_licence * (1-(discount.discountPercentage / 100))}}
```

Now i wish to set:

```
discount.new_value_pr_licence = module.price_pr_licence * (1-(discount.discountPercentage / 100))
```

However im not quite sure how to do that.

How do you bind a variable to such an expression?

Comment: Set it when? On the button click? You could do this if so: ng-click="discount.new_value_pr_licence = module.price_pr_licence * (1-(discount.discountPercentage / 100))"

Comment: @BBauer42 The button is not ment to be clicked ( i know thats abit unclear) but basicly whenever the expression changes the value of discount should be set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can go with a computed property (via an accessor) to keep things clean and also spare angular's expression parser that does not support full JS expression trees..

```
 $scope.module.discount = [{
            licences: 0,
            discountPercentage: 0,
            new_value_pr_licence: 0,
            get discountedPrice() {
                return ($scope.module.someValue + this.someOtherValue / 100)
            }
        }]
```

Then later on you just reference this as

```
 {{discount.discountedPrice}}
```

Fiddle:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/22917/)

Comment: thank you for your response. Will this set the variable equal to it or just display the result of the expression? I need the value to be set since im sending it to my API using HTTP

Comment: on variable you mean field? - it does not set any field/variable to anythig - it just reads them on the spot, but you will perceive this as a field being set to a correct value

Comment: so no :) it is not setting an lvalue to an rvalue

Comment: okay. is there no way i can actually set the field? without having to loop through the list before i send it to a HTTP request to set each field?

Comment: for that I'd use the prototype like this:  function Discount() { }; Object.assign(Discount.prototype, { get discountedPrice() { } }).. then you just instantiate like module.discounts = [new Discount(data), new Discount(data)]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101781/discussion-between-peter-aron-zentai-and-marc-rasmussen).

Comment: can you post that to your question?

Comment: I am happy to extend a jsfiddle with it... so please - help me help.

Comment: not entirely sure this is what you wanted but this is a version http://jsfiddle.net/v1bxyrx1/1/  - I probably do not get your real goal here..